# Can display:auto replace initial keyword on IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility

Working with media queries, I need to be able to use the css keyword "initial".
Unfortunalty it's not suported by Internet Explorer.

Could I replace it by "auto" on another keywork do work around this issue ?

```
/* visibility classes */
.hidden, .hidden-on-phone, .hidden-on-tablet {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: @tablet-screen) {
  .hidden-on-phone {
    display: initial; // not ie compliant
  }
}
@media (min-width: @desktop-screen) {
  .hidden-on-tablet {
    display: initial; // not ie compliant
  }
}
```

Comment: According to http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display there is  no `display initial;` Try to define defaults like `div.initial { display: block; }` or try to use `display: inherit;` but the results will vary.

Comment: @NicoO - In [CSS3CASCADE](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-cascade-20130103/#initial) all properties have an `initial` value. CSS3CASCADE also proposes a `default` value to roll back all properties to their values at the start of the origin (e.g. author non-important styles) but that has outstanding issues and no implementations right now.

Comment: @Alohci yes you are right. My comment was not thought through. As seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial#Browser_compatibility you may use the `initial` property value in all browsers except IE. Is there any article on caniuse.com on this? Thank you for the clarification

Comment: @NicoO I think there's noting on caniuse cause this is not in the css3 spec, it's just a proactive change from browser, and IE didn't jump into it, unfortunatly...